# How to detect changes in Redux form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am new to React-Redux, and am trying to launch an "unsaved changes" dialog whenever the user tries to exit without saving changes.  I thought that Redux does this for you with implementation of isDirty.  I have tried unsuccessfully to implement this; the form always opens with dirty === true, even though no changes were made.  Please tell me what I am doing wrong, or what I can do to detect changes anywhere in the Redux form.

Thus far I have

```
    import { Field, Form, reduxForm, change, isDirty } from 'redux-form';
        ...
            this.state = {
                    dirty: isDirty('ClientViewForm'),
        ...
    public onCancel = (close: boolean) => {
            if (this.state.dirty) {
                this.showUnsavedChangesDialog();
            } 
        }
    ...
    public showUnsavedChangesDialog = () => {
        this.setState({ displayUnsavedChangesDialog: true })
    }
```

and in the Redux form:

```
<Dialog appendTo={document.body} header="Unsaved Changes Exist" onHide={thisComponent.hideUnsavedChangesDialog} modal={true} visible={thisComponent.state.displayUnsavedChangesDialog}>
                <div className={classes.generalDialog}>
                    <div className="p-3">
                        You have made edits.  If you close without saving, you will lose your changes.
                            </div>
                    <div className="dialogFooter">
                        <Button label="Close without Saving" onClick={thisComponent.props.onHide} />
                        <Button label="Cancel" onClick={thisComponent.hideUnsavedChangesDialog} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </Dialog>
```

This is not working, again, because when I first open the form, dirty is already set to true.  Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isDirty` is not an action creator. It's a selector. You have to put it inside `mapStateToProps` and pass `state` as the second argument.

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
   isDirty: isDirty('ClientViewForm')(state),
});
```

Then simply initialize it in your state:

```
this.state = {
   isDirty: this.props.isDirty,
};
```

When it changes, your component will be automatically re-rendered.

Comment: I have tried this.  Now my onCancel code is "if (this.state.isDirty) {
            this.showUnsavedChangesDialog()};"  Now the unsaved changes dialog doesn't fire even when the form is dirty.

Comment: @Pismotality Because you are using `state` and not `setState` anywhere so the component could re-render. I suggest you to not use state, in your `onCancel` method use just `if (this.props.isDirty)`

Comment: I tried that too, but now when the form opens this.props.isDirty is set to true.

Comment: @Pismotality If your form initializes with `dirty` set to `true`, you are doing something wrong. The `dirty` prop is `true` only if you have changed any of the form values.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  The developer who wrote this code included some methods in the form that were setting isDirty to true on load.  When I commented them out your method works great.  Thank you!